# Dwarf Fortress can't load the Stonesense Plugin file 'Stonesense.plug.so'

Tags: dwarf-fortress, linux

I am trying to run dfhack's Stonesense plugin through my linux terminal
and I run across errors that make the Stonesense plugin unavailable and not listed in the dfhack list

Here are the logs of my stderr.log

> liballegro.so.5.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory Can't load plugin
>   /home/user/df_linux/hack/plugins/stonesense.plug.so Plugin
>   /home/user/df_linux/hack/plugins/mapexport.plug.so has no name,
>   version or self pointer. Plugin
>   /home/user/df_linux/hack/plugins/dwarfexport.plug.so has no name,
>   version or self pointer.
>   /home/user/df_linux/hack/plugins/advtools.plug.so: undefined
>   symbol: _ZN6DFHack13color_ostream5colorENS0_11color_valueE Can't load
>   plugin /home/user/df_linux/hack/plugins/advtools.plug.so

Stonesense version is the one from the default Beautato's Linux Lazy Newb Pack available on the bay12 forums

I have also installed the allegro5.0 library

Comment: Ive had a similar issue on Win, and I had thought there was some mention of Stonesense being separated out, but I never got to the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get stonesense working by git cloning the offical repo on github
Link is [here](https://github.com/Lazy-Newb-Pack/Lazy-Newb-Pack-Linux/)